# Find and get array of JSON in a given text

Tags: javascript

I have a text string with multiple JSON in it example:

> some text { "title":"Google", "description":"Search webpages, images,
>   videos and more." } then again some text { "title":"Google",
>   "description":"Search webpages, images, videos and more." } some text
>   again

This is the JSON I may have multiple time in the string:

```
    {
"title":"xyz",
"description":"xyz",
"image":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/logo.png",
"url":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/"
}
```

Is there any way to get all the JSON string in an array.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: could you please be little more specific, so that we can help you.

Comment: do you know what text you get in between jsons?

Comment: have you tried using regex to pull out the JSON from the string?

Comment: If the objects are all flat / one-level deep, just pull the strings between and including `{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the objects don't contain nested objects, this (very naïve) approach might work:

```js
var text = `some text { "title":"Google", "description":"Search webpages, images, videos and more." } then again some text { "title":"Google", "description":"Search webpages, images, videos and more." } some text again`;

const results = [].concat.apply(
    [], 
    text.split('{').map(part => part.split('}'))
  )
  .filter((_, i) => i % 2)
  .map(part => `{${part}}`)
  .map(json => {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(json);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  })
  .filter(Boolean);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to get all the values. Or you use `map` to get the values. Below are examples for both:

```js
var obj = {
  "title": "xyz",
  "description": "xyz",
  "image": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/logo.png",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/"
};
var arr = Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr);

var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  return obj[k]
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to get all the matching JSON strings:

```
var re = new RegExp(/\{\s*"title"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"description":\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"image":\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"url":\s*(.+?)\s*}/, 'g');
var text = 'some text { "title":"Google", "description":"1. Search webpages, images, videos and more.", "image": "image1", "url": "url1" } then again some text { "title":"Google", "description":"2. Search webpages, images, videos and more.", "image": "image2", "url": "url2"} some text again';
var matches = text.match(re);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve - I think you want to capture all JSON objects, so regex may help. Now I'm no regex expert and this is a super quick hack, but you can parse the string with

```
var str = YOUR _STRING_HERE;

// this is in no way fault tolerant
var rgx = /\{[^\}]*\}/g;

var jsons = [];
var match;

while ((match = rgx.exec(str)) !== null) {
  jsons.push(match[0]);
}

// do something useful with your JSONs
console.log(jsons);
```